# How to say about waiting time change "waiting time was ..."?

Tags: phrase-usage

I want to use some phrase with waiting time and not sure if they are valid and not artificial:

1. *waiting time was reduced **by** 10 minutes* - was 20 minutes and now is 10 minutes
2. *waiting time was **extended by** 10 minutes* - was 10 minutes and now is 20 minutes
3. *waiting time was **extended to** one month* - was something less than and now is month

*waiting time* - I mean as time to wait for something.

How will native speakers say in the most natural way?

Answer (score 6):

The phrase *waiting time* is both natural and common. The phrase *wait time* is sometimes used as well.

[Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20waiting%20time,the%20wait%20time&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that *waiting time* is the more prevalent of the two, but *wait time* has been gaining traction for the past couple decades.

As for the verbs and prepositions you've used, those are fine – English has quite a few verbs that can be (and are frequently) used in this context. If the original wait time was 17 minutes and the new waiting time is 7 minutes, you could say any of these:

> The waiting time was...
>    - reduced by 10 minutes
>    - decreased by 10 minutes
>    - lessened by 10 minutes
>    - shortened to 7 minutes

When the numbers are 20 and 10, you can use either *by* or *to*, because the wait time is both reduced *by* 10 minutes, and *to* 10 minutes. Therefore, either preposition could be used in that special case, but those two expressions – while both true – would mean two different things.